# Is there a way/strategy to locate element if multiple elements are in the same xcuielement - Appium python

Tags: python, ios, automation, appium

I want to locate the element using appium inspector, app is running on iOS simulator

- When clicked on desired place to find locator.
- Almost whole screen is showing as one xcuielement.
- One long xpath is showing for the whole screen.
- I want to fetch particular element, assume that is available on bottom right corner. when tapped bottom right corner, whole screen get selected.

Need to automate could you please share any strategy to find these type of locators.

App is made using react-native

Tried the random click using x and y coordinates, that's not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.